# Switch to zsh only for current user after ssh into remote server using sudo?

Tags: command-line, server, bash, ssh, zsh

As title. I just `ssh`ed into my lab's server and it's Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. But I'm a macOS user and I have gotten used to zsh, but the shell of the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server defaults to `/bin/sh`. My current path is at `/home/my_school_id/`. These are what I concerned:

1. I don't want to change anything from `/home/my_lab_mate_school_id/`.
2. I don't want to change ALL users to use zsh. So is it possible to always automatically activate/switch to zsh just for me? Doing this manually is also OK for me.
3. I want to use `sudo apt install some_pkg`. Would I potentially update some pkgs(upgrade it's version or so) my labmates are using?
4. If zsh can be installed only for me. Where should I put my .zshrc file? Can I put it inside `/home/my_school_id/`? I don't want to put it outside of this folder!

Thanks in advance. I'm really new to multi-user management of Ubuntu/Linux.

Comment: Do you even have admin access to the server for (3)? You should be asking your lab's system administrators for support. As for (2), it should be easy enough for them to install zsh and then for you to change your shell yourself using `chsh` or have them change it for you.

Comment: @muru: I just got the access for (3).